# How to check a radio button of main form from another form in c#?

Tags: c#

//It is the main form :

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class frmCYW : Form
{
    public frmCYW()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rbtnFemale.Checked == true || rbtnMale.Checked == true)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please first select your gender.");

        }

    }

}

}
```

//and it is the second form :

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public frmCYW f1;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        f1 = new frmCYW();
    }

    private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmCYW f1 =new frmCYW();
        if(f1.rbtnMale==true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Good");

            }

    }
}

}
```

but it give me this error:

Error   1   'WindowsFormsApplication2.frmCYW.rbtnMale' is inaccessible due to its protection level  C:\Users\Ibrahim\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\Form2.cs   25  19  WindowsFormsApplication2 */

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the rbtnMale access modifiers property in properties window. You should click to frmCYW form and than open properties. F4 is a shortcut's property window. And then change to access modifier private from public.

Answer (score 2):

The thing you got the problem is that the RadioButton have its modifier set to private in order to see anything from other classes you have to define it as public see it here
[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms173121.aspx)
so you should set its Modifiers property inside the category Design to public